# I wrote you a message

Tags: cipher

Take the dogs out for Millan, but only after you find the alphas.

> dog 1234 Ny nx
>
> dog 556 fqrtxy Fzlzxy 567
>
> dog 5819 gzy 2 nx 345
>
> dog 13445 fqwjfid 74859 mty. 55645788
>
> dog 1234 Xyfd 5678 kwtxyd! 9101112

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a

> Caesar cypher

since we take out the dogs for

> Cesar Millan

I guess the alphas refer to

> the dogs, which are 5

Using this we get:

> It is almost August but is already hot. Stay frosty!

Comment: Is your third word ‘already’ or is it ‘almost’? Seems like it’s 6 letters, not 7...

Comment: You are right, its 'almost'. Dont know how it got there...

Comment: Correct, but finding the alphas referred to removing the numbers altogether (find the alphabet)